# Custom editor in Slick Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I need to write a custom editor for slick grid. I want to be able to pass in a regex and an error message to output.

This article explains what I need to do

[Slickgrid Validation](http://www.megalomaniacslair.co.uk/programming/slickgrid-validation/)

The article is clear what to do and I understand it, but I don't like that I have to edit a file that's part of the slick grid package. The reason I don't like this is that I work on a large team of developers and we are not located together and we also use a package manager to manage updates to our packages.

Has anyone done this in a better way that will avoid editing a package file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors are bound to columns, so you can make editor inline by just passing it as a function to column property:

```
column.editor = function(args) { }
```

This function should implement all the functions that are in basic editors: [slick.editors.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js).